# Core Service - Get schemas for component's & CT's

Tags: 2013, core-service

The code below works for returning all pages for the listed publication, along with the CT's & CP's referenced by those pages.  How can I easily get the schemas used by the PT's &  CT's  also?  I don't want to list all schemas, just the ones actually being used.

```
RepositoryItemsFilterData filter = GetPageFilter();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
client = new CoreServiceSession().GetClient;

IdentifiableObjectData[] pages = client.GetList("tcm:0-999-1", filter);

    foreach (IdentifiableObjectData iod in pages)
    {

        PageData pageData = client.Read(iod.Id, new ReadOptions())  as PageData;

        sb.AppendLine("Page: " + pageData.Title);

        foreach (ComponentPresentationData cpd in pageData.ComponentPresentations)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("CP: " + cpd.Component.Title);
            sb.AppendLine("CT: " + cpd.ComponentTemplate.Title);
        }

        //blank line for readability
         sb.AppendLine("");
        }

            return "";
```

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Yes. I've deleted my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're searching for the Content schema, then in your ComponentPresentation loop you can load the component and *then* read the schema ID or Title from it:

```
ComponentData c = (ComponentData) client.Read(cpd.Component.IdRef, readOptions);
sb.AppendLine("Schema:" + c.Schema.Title;
```

If you're searching for Metadata schemas that may be used by the Page or Component Templates, then you can follow the same approach, but loading the Component Template object instead (you already have the Page object outside the loop, so you wouldn't have to load it).

Or use `.IdRef` instead of `.Title` if you need the TcmUri.

Comment: I don't see a Schema property/object in cpd.Component.

Comment: You're right - too many years using TOM.NET... updating answer...

Comment: Thanks!  That worked, though I needed to cast the result of Client.Read to see the Schema property: ComponentData c = (ComponentData)client.Read(cpd.Component.IdRef, new ReadOptions());

Comment: Yeah, otherwise it's an "IdentifiableObjectData". I'll fix that later, glad it worked